# Cannot add a controller ...Unable to retrieve metadata for 'project.model'. Unable to load one or more of the requested types

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Please help me to Create a **controller and View** form the **Model and DB context of  EDMX file** which is in **another Project** of same solution.

I have two project named  domain and DAL in the same solution. I have Created DB first. With help this DB and **Entity Framework**, I have created Edmx file in the DAL project. Now Try to create a  view and controller using the Model and DB context of the project DAL in the project Domain.
I have received the following error.
**Unable to retrieve metadata for 'DAL.Model.Exam'. Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.**

[Structure of Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1ioo.jpg)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wd0OW.jpg)

I have used DB in local server

connection string

```
      '<connectionStrings>  
 <add name="OnlineDBEFEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.OnlineDB.csdl|res://*/Model.OnlineDB.ssdl|res://*/Model.OnlineDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=OnlineDBEF;persist security info=True;user id=sa;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
        providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please also read [How do I ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad.

Comment: got the solution ..Naming mismatch between DBcontext and Model Namesspace